# Is there a publicly available Cardano API with pre-indexed blockchain data?

Tags: api, proof-of-stake, transaction-metadata

I'm looking for a public API that has idempotent endpoints that can be used to query for transaction data for a given address. Specifically, I'm looking for reward payout data. Does this exist in this ecosystem?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Yes, have a look at [blockfrost.io](https://blockfrost.io/) an API as a service that allows users to interact with the Cardano blockchain and parts of its ecosystem.

Comment: Thank you for this

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can also try a community driven project https://dandelion.link/

Comment: Awesome ill check this one out